# Entity Framework: selecting from multiple tables

Tags: entity-framework

I have a statement:

```
var items = from e in db.Elements
    join a in db.LookUp
    on e.ID equals a.ElementID
    where e.Something == something
    select new Element
    {
        ID = e.ID,
        LookUpID = a.ID
        // some other data get populated here as well
    };
```

As you can see, all I need is a collection of Element objects with data from both tables - Elements and LookUp. This works fine. But then I need to know the number of elements selected:

```
int count = items.Count();
```

... this call throws System.NotSupportedException:

"The entity or complex type 'Database.Element' cannot be constructed in a LINQ to Entities query."

How am I supposed to select values from multiple tables into one object in Entity Framework? Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code doesn't work at all. The part you think worked has never been executed. The first time you executed it was when you called `Count`.

As exception says you cannot construct mapped entity in projection. Projection can be made only to anonymous or non mapped types. Also it is not clear why you even need this. If your class is correctly mapped you should simply call:

```
var items = from e in db.Elements
            where e.Something == something
            select e;
```

If `LookupID` is mapped property of your `Element` class it will be filled. If it is not mapped property you will not be able to load it with single query to `Element`.

Comment: Do I have to map tables into a single object for every join that I will ever need? I guess I'm simply missing something here.

Comment: Is `LookupID` part of `Element` table? If yes you don't need to do nothing more. If not you cannot load that property in entity mapped to `Element` table - it is not allowed. You must instead create new class (not mapped) with all needed properties and project result of your query into that new class instead of `Element`.

Comment: That's what I was afraid of. No, the LookUpID is not in the Elements table, the point of joining those two tables was to get that value together with the Element. Makes the one think why to use that EF stuff in the first place :) Thanks for the clarification, though.

Answer (score 2):

You are not allowed to create an Entity class in your projection, you have to either project to a new class or an anonymous type

```
select new 
{
        ID = e.ID,
        LookUpID = a.ID
        // some other data get populated here as well
};
```